# How to print line numbers changed by sed / awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Is it possible to print the line number and the line content that have been changed by sed?

I just need a simple text replace, no regex is needed:

```
sed -i "s:replace_me:replaced:" test.c
```

I will need it for a bash script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would [tag:awk] be okay? - Note that [tag:sed] cannot print this info because it would end up in the infile. I know you use `-i` but internally it will output to a temp file and move it back to the original.

Comment: Sure! also can be as ugly as it has to be. I just want a confirmation about changed lines and preferably the line content. Thanks for help

Comment: Just do it twice, once to stdout, once in place.  Or backup the file and use diff after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could swing it a couple ways:

## vim

Using a text editor you can interactively replace patterns, the editor will prompt before every substitution. So you can choose `y` or `n` for each case.

```
$ vim file
:%s/pattern/replace/gc
```

## diff

Using diff you can easily compare two files and see the changes:

```
$ sed 's/pattern/replace/g' file > tmpfile
$ diff -u file tmpfile
```

or

```
$ diff -y file tmpfile
```

Play around with `man diff` for other cool visualizations.

Then when you're sure it's okay, do:

```
$ mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: If this is insufficient, I can write an [tag:awk] script which performs the replacement and stores information to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

It's an extension to POSIX, but `cat -n file.txt | ...` is an elegant solution to adding line numbers.

You could try creating the updated file with `sed`, run both the original and updated files through `cat -n` to temp. files, and then `diff -q` the both of the latter.

Another approach, something along the lines of `cat -n original.txt | sed -n 's/[ 0-9]{7} .*pattern.*/replacement/gp`.  You would have to run the replace twice, but by the time you have numbered and `diff`'d original and updated files then the only plus is `diff` could be considered more textbook technique possibly.